# Making sure the leftmost 16 bits are zero using sll and srl only?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to come up with a way to ensure the leftmost 16 bits of a register are zero, without affecting the rightmost 16 bits, using sll and srl only.

I have been playing around with bits for hours now with no success. I was able to ensure the leftmost bits are zero, but I cannot do this without affecting the rightmost bits, using sll/srl only.

Comment: Hint: You may change the right-most bits -- but what can you do to reverse that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure, I wasn't aware there was a 'reverse' operation in assembly, plus I am trying to accomplish this using sll/srl only :/

Comment: I didn't say there was a `reverse` operation in assembly.  But, using `sll` and `slr` it is possible to move (affect, as you said) the rightmost bits.  But, it is possible to affect them in the /other/ direction -- using *just* the two instructions you have.

Comment: Of course, if you don't restrict yourself to using `sll` and `srl`, you can do this in a single instruction: `lui $t0,0` (load upper immediate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sll 16. This results in the right 16 being zero and the right 16 bits being shifted into the left 16 bits. Then srl 16. This will shift the 16 bits you want back into the rightmost 16 bits and shift zeros into the leftmost 16 bits.

Comment: Aww.. and I was trying to get the OP into that 'ah-ha!' moment where he got it.